# What skill to use for a parkour run?

Tags: skills, d6-system, star-wars-d6

As the D6 system has split the skills quite strongly (acrobatics, climbing, jumping, ...), I'm not exactly sure what would be best in terms of handling Parkour running.

Naturally I want to avoid letting the players roll 3-4 different skills for just 1 single action (as parkour is a complete mix between acrobatics, climbing, jumping, running).

Would with how skills work in D6 it be appropriate to just use the skill that would be the most useful for a specific route and roll only that one and disregard the other skills?
(thus if a specific route is mostly jumping from roof to roof then roll jumping, if a route is mostly moving over obstacles and around them, through them,... then acrobatics, or if its mostly running a straight line and avoiding passers by then running)

OR is there a different way to handle this?

Comment: Do you expect the character to be using parkour to gain an advantage in combat, for rapid transportation, for making strong first impressions, or something else?

Comment: Tbh I NEVER had a player improvising enough so far to use parkour effectively in combat, but due to the nature of the question (current formulation) I fear all 3 of those things are included

Comment: That was kind of my point: I don't know enough about d6 to compose an answer, but in many games *what* a character wants to accomplish is far more important than *how* it's accomplished. So saying, "I parkour across the street by walking atop the cars," is as valid as, "I stop traffic with my winning smile and cross the street safely." But, as I said, I don't know if that sort of refluffing is a thing in d6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Consider the challenges on the route, and try to figure out which one is **the hardest/most challenging/most interesting**. Have your player roll the appropriate skill for that challenge as the critical moment of the experience.
- If it's a predetermined route, roll the lowest skill involved, as the biggest challenge a character must **overcome is their own shortcomings**.
- If the character can make their own route and **put their strengths forward**, (ie. they aren't constrained to a specific route to take) then have the player pick the skill they want to roll.

In any case, the choice of skill should have an impact on the cost of failure. What happens when you fail your acrobatics, break a few bones or make yourself look silly? What happens when you fail your athletics, exhausted or too late to finish?

Consider and make a decision on a case-by-case basis.